# Statistical Significance of a 3D Volume

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, image-processing

I have two 3D volumes of a single patient. One 3D volume before surgery and one 3D volume after surgery. The 3D volumes are MRI images (Mangetic resonance imaging). Each 3D volume has dimensions [100, 100, 25]. The values in every voxel gives me the blood flow. I've been told to find statistical significance. What I originally done is to calculate the mean value of each 3D volume. I have only two mean values one pre and one post. So there is no way to find statistical significance with these two values.

What I have thought to do but I don't know if it's correct is to calculate the mean in every slice so I will have 25 mean values pre and 25 post surgery. Then run a pair test to check significance. Would that be correct?

Comment: What would you exactly count as two "different volumes"? Can two volumes have the same mean and still be different in some relevant way? Do permutations of slices count?

Comment: The two different volumes is the MRI scans before and after the surgery. Permutations of slices don't count

Comment: Then... Apart from overall mean, what other features could make one volume different from the other?

Comment: The two volumes basically show the liver before and after the surgery. The volume of the liver is exactly the same. What is changed is the blood flow. Each pixel gives me the blood flow of a particular location. That's why I calculated the mean

Comment: If you think your 25 averages over slices for each MRI give independent indications of blood flow it seems reasonable to do a two-sample test to see if there is a difference in blood flow before and after. A Welch 2-sample t test may be OK unless you observations are very far from normal or have many far outliers. // You might give us a look at histograms of before and after observations for advice based on what is really happening.

Comment: If it is possible to isolate the same 50 'particular locations' before and after surgery then you would have paired data, and possibly a more powerful test of the difference.

Comment: I think it's tremendously unlikely that you can consider the individual voxels independent. This is a situation where you should not be using statistical hypothesis testing and instead just rely on descriptive statistics.

Comment: I calculated mean and standard deviation. What else can I calculate to give me some clue of the data if I only need to rely on descriptive statistics?

Comment: @Gina Unless you have reason to believe that the values you measure have uncorrelated (in space) noise in them and you are trying to tell if there is a difference relative to that uncorrelated noise, then really all you can do is say how much the means are different by. You basically have the entire population of 1 sampled already, so the blood flow is definitely different, it's up to other considerations to decide whether that amount of difference is relevant clinically or not.

Comment: @BryanKrause you mean to calculate the means in every slice and see how much difference there is?

Comment: No, the entire volume. One number. The slices are arbitrary and irrelevant.

Comment: I did calculate the mean of the entire volume, but I wanted to see if there are statistically significant. If I then calculate the difference of the means I still cannot show statical significance right?